# windowsログイン時にrailsを自動的に起動させたい

Tags: bash, windows-10

windows10にBash on Ubuntu on Windowsをインストールしてrailsを使っています。
windowsを立ち上げたあと、毎回ディレクトリを変更してからrailsを起動させているのを、
windowsログイン時に自動的にrailsを立ち上げるようにしたいのですが、何か方法はないでしょうか？
rails起動までに実行しているコマンドは以下の通りです。

［動作環境］
・windows10
・ruby:2.4.1
・rails:5.1.2
・Bash on Ubuntu on Windows

［実行コマンド］

```
C:\Users\username\Desktop>cd C:\Users\username\rails\rails_app
C:\Users\username\rails\rails_app>bash
username@TEST1:mnt/Users/username/rails/rails_app$rails s
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
`bash -c "rails s"` を実行してみたのですが、`/bin/bash: rails: コマンドが見つかりません`と表示されます。何が間違っているのでしょうか？ご教授よろしくお願いします。

Comment: bash -l -c '(cd /mnt/Users/username/rails/rails_app ; rails s)'
ではどうでしょう？
これでだめなら、criticabugさんのコメント通りですね。

Answer (score 1):

毎回実行しているコマンドをスタートアップに登録するのがよさそうですね。
PowerShell で

```powershell
start "${env:APPDATA}\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"
```

と実行するとスタートアップ フォルダーが開くので、ここで新規ショートカット作成
`bash -c "`（実行しているコマンド）`"`
です。コマンドが複数あるなら `;` でつなげて全部ダブルクォートの中に入れます

Comment: @toyokoko bash が rails コマンドを見つけられなかったとのこと、 `~/.profile` などで PATH 環境変数などを設定しているのなら同じ状況にする必要があります。 rails, ruby はどうやってインストールしましたか？ いつもの `cd`, `bash` したあと次の実行結果を教えてもらえればなにか分かるかもしれません: `which rails`, `head $(which rails)`, `which ruby` （信用度スコアがたらず自分へのコメントで）